# Keyword density and instance php script

Tags: php, regex

I am usng the following script but its not working, It keeps saying there is only once instance of the keyword

Maybe it  has something to do with the special character? Not sure how to fix it though

```
   $word_count = explode(' ', "estudiar inglés estudiar inglés asdasd asd asd sadasd estudiar ingles adas dasd estudiar inglés");
$word_count = count($word_count);
$keyword= "estudiar inglés";

echo $keyword;

$keyword_count = preg_match_all("#{$keyword}#si", $text, $matches);
$keyword_count = count($matches);

$density = $keyword_count / $word_count * 100;

$density = number_format($density, 2) . '%';

              echo $keyword_count;
```

Comment: Where is `$text` defined, besides in your `preg_match_all()` call?

Comment: Thanks however i found the main problem is how special characters are stored in my database as so "estudiar ingl&eacute;s"  so the script doesnt find it. How can I combat this?

Answer (score 0):

This work:

```
$text       = "some text asoijw oijd cj isoj some text asiojoasj aisojsaij";

$word_count = explode(' ',$text);
$word_count = count($word_count);
$keyword    = "some text";

$keyword_count = preg_match_all("/$keyword/i", $text, $matches);
$keyword_count = count($matches[0]);

$density = $keyword_count / $word_count * 100;
$density = number_format($density, 2) . '%';

echo "Text: $text<br/>"
    ."Keyword: $keyword<br/><br/>"
    ."Matched $keyword_count time(s)<br/>"
    ."Density: $density";
```

**$matches[0]**: preg_match_all split matches into subarrays

Comment: Thanks however i found the main problem is how special characters are stored in my database as so "estudiar ingl&eacute;s"  so the script doesnt find it. How can I combat this?

Comment: Decode the html entities with htmlentities_decode()

http://php.net/html_entity_decode